# Serializing custom and complex types with MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've been working with the MongoDB C# driver and I am now converting my work to PyMongo. My largest need right now is being able to write Python classes. To do this, I am now converting the classes to dictionaries using "obj.**dict**". There are some main problems which I need to overcome:

1. I want to be able to write complex classes, such as classes containing other class objects (nested).
2. I want to be able to write unknown classes, i.e write classes without having to specify their structure before writing them to the database.
3. I want to be able to deserialize objects from the database into classes easily.

The C# driver is able to do both these without me having to write any code. However, the PyMongo driver seems much more naive. I have checked out some ORMs but they seem to rely largely on the fact that the class structures are known (which inhibits my need #2).

I am searching for an easy way of serializing these type of objects without having to write all the code myself.

Comment: I think this is one of the advantages of using a language like C# versus Python for a case like this. Moreover, it's not clear at all how you want things serialized. What if your Python class has a function member. How do you serialize that? What if it has a member that is a class? There's a ton of possibilities that might be handled in a use-case specific way, so in the end if you want to handle everything I think you need to use something like pickle or just convert to a binary representation that will be fairly useless in the database (no way to query its pieces without adding extra fields)

Comment: I agree with some of your points, however, since the C# driver can handle these problems so seemlessly, I don't see why the PyMongo driver can't. For example, a nested class is simply stored as a nested document with the C# mongo driver. You would think there would be an easy way to do this using the PyMongo driver, but so far I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

[Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) offers tool for marshalling objects.

Comment: I want the solution to be used in MongoDB. I have considered pickling the objects first then storing them in the database but that seems very ineffective.

Comment: My bad ! Have you compared performance with cPickle? Documentation proudly states that it can be 1000 times faster than Pickle.